# useEffect is not called unless a not related useState is set to true

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and having trouble with useState/useEffect :

```
function WinesInMyCave() {
  const [winesList, setWinesList] = useState({});
  const [isDataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Got this far 1");
    async function fetchWine() {
      console.log("Got this far 2");
      setDataLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/wines", {
        method: "GET",
      })
      const { winesList } = await response.json()
      setWinesList(winesList)
      setDataLoading(false)
    }
    fetchWine()
  }, []);

  console.log(winesList);
  console.log(isDataLoading);

return (
...
)
```

With the console.logs I added, I see that the useEffect is never called, thus the function fetchWine is not called either.

And if I set
  `const [isDataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(**true**);`

I see that the useEffect is called ("Got this far" 1 & 2 showing)

Can somebody help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I, as well can't see the problem, `useEffect`'s Effect would run once after `WinesInMyCave` has initially rendered. "*Can somebody help*" to help with what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to leave only the function call in the useEffect.

Place the function itself outside

Also, set loading to false only once you have your data.

The code should look something like this :

```
function WinesInMyCave() {
  const [winesList, setWinesList] = useState({});
  const [isDataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fetchWine() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/wines", {
      method: "GET",
    })
    const { winesList } = await response.json()
    setWinesList(winesList)
    setDataLoading(false)
    console.log(winesList);
    console.log(isDataLoading);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWine()
  }, []);

return (
...
)
```

Comment: "Place the function itself outside" for what purpose ? When you can create it inside the `useEffect` and have a boost of performance to not re-create the function `fetchWine` whenever `WinesInMyCave` re-renders.

Comment: Hi, 

First of all : thank you for helping !

I edited my code following your advices, which did not solve the problem...

Comment: I edited my response, to place the logs in the function.
useEffect should be called and the logs should appear, since they are declared after the the api call is done (after the 'await').

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
function WinesInMyCave() {
const [winesList, setWinesList] = useState([]);
const [isDataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
async function fetchWine() {
  setDataLoading(true);
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/wines", {
    method: "GET",
  });
  const winesList = await response.json();
  setWinesList(winesList);
  setDataLoading(false);
}
fetchWine();
}, []);

return (
...
)
```

I had set winesList has an object, but the API send an array, furthermore it needed to delete the {} for  `const { winesList } = await response.json()` as it was not needed to deconstruct the constant.

Thanks for you help !